# Assembly - When use macro (in terms of efficiency)?

Tags: assembly, macros, x86

When it prefer to use macro, in order to achieve more efficiency program? 
As I understood it, when we use macro we spend more binary code and we lose some running time. So it prefer to write the relevant macro in the code.

(I aware of the advantages of macro to simple the code for the programmer, I ask about the efficiency)

Thanks

Comment: False premise - there is no reason why a macro should be less efficient - it just saves writing "boilerplate" code.

Comment: Macros generate less efficient code because it isn't that obvious to the programmer what *actual* machine code gets generated.  Macros generate more efficient code because it allows the programmer to spend more brain cycles on the parts of the code that actually matter for perf.  Pick one.

Answer (score 3):

Is a macro efficient?  Why wouldn't it be?  It just saves you from writing the same code over again.  Let's say in Windows you send WM_COMMAND quite a few times, instead of writing this:

```
mov ax, HiWord
ror eax, 16
mov ax, LoWord
```

each time, you put it into a macro:

```
  MAKEDWORD MACRO LoWord,HiWord
    mov ax, HiWord
    ror eax, 16
    mov ax, LoWord
  ENDM
```

Now all you have to do is:
MAKEDWORD somenumber, somenumber and the result will be in eax to pass to a function.  The Preprocessor will replace all instances of MAKEDWORD with its code.  The downside (at least I feel it is) of using macros, is if you use it MANY times, you will get "code bloat", you would be better to change the macro to a function if you are going to use it many times.

Comment: Yes, but if I use the macro, for example, only one time. So in this case, It will be less efficient to writa a macro, and it prefers to write it in the code. No?

Comment: A macro is as efficient as the code you write for it.  A Macro is nothing special really, it is just a marker for the preprocessor that says, hey, replace all occurrences of this line with this code.  A macro is just a tool to make your code writing easier and code less cluttered.

Comment: hi I have question, is it valid to put macro inside a macro?

Answer (score 2):

With current processors (at least x86-like), I can't imagine a case when macro gives efficiency, in sense of speeding up execution. One can compare which tricks are used by compilers to generate code effective for particular processor - the same action can be implemented with changing commands, registers, etc. With macro, you stick to concrete registers, commands, their ordering; all this doesn't give efficiency. The notable exception is when macro is implementation of command which isn't known to the particular assembler.

Instead, nowadays one can use intermediate language (as LLVM does) on output of some macroprocessor and them conversion to machine language according to required tuning. But this isn't macro usage by itself:)

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with assembly.  Macros are for saving typing, which in some cases can allow you to write more code in a day.  Or debug more code in a day.  Or maintain more code in a day.  You can use macros in C the same as ASM for exactly the same reasons.  Likewise you can use functions, in a number of cases the functions do cost you something runtime with branch and stack stuff over a macro, but your macros might be written such that they cost you something as well.

If not driven by company or project programming standards then it comes down to individual preferences.  some folks program linearly and once some block of code (has nothing to do with the language) is typed twice in more than one place and there is a risk that it might be changed, depending on that risk it might get put into a macro or function.  Often just cut and pasted the first pass on the program and IF when debugging it has to change then a function is made and the multiple locations are then replaced with a function.  The other extreme is out of the gate to come up with a myriad of utility functions.  utility functions layered on utility functions, etc.  Such that ultmately the main program is maybe 5 lines long, each function is like a dozen lines long, all calling other helper functions.   Reality is somewhere in the middle.  It all comes down to typing and the side effect of typing, initial development, debugging and maintenance down the road.  The less typing you do the faster you get those things done.

Comment: where you have to be careful is that macros in assembly are very often specific to the assembler tool and not the processor, in other words not portable across the same platform or processor.  A macro in other languages may or may not be.  So you have to be very careful with too much macro use as down the road the program may have to be discarded completely or re-written/ported as tools come and go.

Answer (score 1):

You should use macro when the sequence of instructions is extremly short, because it saves some cycles from `call` and `return`.